# How to keep textarea text selection stay there even it lose focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this function to get the selected text from textarea

```
function getSelText(){
    var text = "";
    if(window.getSelection){
        text = window.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.getSelection){
        text = document.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.selection){
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```

I have a textarea and a link in my document like this

```
 <textarea id="txtarea2" cols="50" rows="10">This is Some Text</textarea>
 <a href="#" onclick="alert(getSelText())">Click Me</a>
```

When I select any text from the document (but not from textarea) and click the 'Click Me' Link it alerts the Selected Text. But When I Select Text from Textarea and click the 'Click Me' Link it alerts the Empty dialog box
Then I Tried

```
window.onmouseup = function() {
    alert(getSelText());
}
```

This function alerts the selected value either I select from the document Or from the textarea. So, It means that the function is correct.

Now, one reason comes to my mind, That When I select any portion of text from textarea and Click the 'Click Me' Link the selection disappears from the textarea, But When I select any text from the document and click the 'Click Me' Link the selection stays there. May be due to this reason it gives the empty value from textarea selection because selection goes disappear when I click the 'Click Me' Link. You may better analyse this.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle out of it?

Comment: I think its not possible..!

Comment: @suresh.g, If it is not possible, then How can I get selected text from textarea? Any other solution?

Comment: @RashidFarooq, you can use window.onselect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onselect